# The vnstat hour graph is not aligned properly in conky

Tags: conky

I am currently using ubuntu budgie 20.10. I have been trying to make a conky script to display the hourly data usage stats and usage graph by using `vnstat -i wlp5s0 -hg`. But the graph and the text are not aligned as the should be. I have done this before but I formatted by laptop and didn't backup the conky script. Can anyone help me with this?

Current view (the center one):

[image: this is the current view. {the center one}]

[image: Earlier it used to look like this]

This is the current code.

```
background no
update_interval 1
update_run_times 0
total_run_times 0

cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

tex_buffer_size 1024
imlib_cache_size 0

own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_type normal #visual #display  ##-- other options are: conky/override/dock/desktop/panel --##
own_window_transparent no
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 128
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_hints below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,undecorated

border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no
top_name_width 7
default_graph_size 26 80

minimum_size 680 610
maximum_width 610
alignment middle_left
gap_x 10
gap_y -20

use_xft yes
override_utf8_locale yes
xftfont Droid Sans:size=8
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no
use_spacer none

default_outline_color AAAAAA
default_shade_color AAAAAA
default_color 44cccc
color1 242424

short_units yes
pad_percents 2

TEXT
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
${color0}${goto 5}Today ${goto 100}Yesterday
${color2}${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp5s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print $8" "substr ($9, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 110}${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp5s0 | grep "yesterday" | awk '{print $8" "substr ($9, 1, 1)}'}
${color2}${alignr}${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp5s0 -hg}
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
```

Comment: Nothing in this question seems to have anything to do with an unstated version of Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean? I am currently using Ubuntu budgie 22.10 on lightdm. Current theme is pocillo. the version of conky is latest one as I installed it today only.

Comment: Nothing in the question says that so how was anyone to know? Please edit the question and add this info.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer. The problem was the font being used. I replaced the font with monospace and things are back in order once again.